# calculation using php mysql conditions

Tags: php, html, mysql, math

I am not really trying to do much, I am trying to checkthe variables matches that of the value on the table and if it does it increases the value stored in $mark.

i.e. 2/5 correct in the quiz gives $mark value 40.

Currently, what it does is output saying it has the value 100 even if the check "should" fail.

If anyone could possibly tell me how I am messing this up I would appreciate it. :D

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ircQ4.png)

---

PHP Page where I am trying to calculate.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
include ("dbfunctions.php");


//print first part of html
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<title>Results</title>  
</head>
<body>
<h1>Results</h1>


<?php
//retrieve username and password
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

//connect to database
$dbConn = dbConnect("$username", "$password") ;
dbSelect($dbConn, "$username");

//retrieve pet and number of tins from the form
$question1 = $_POST['question1'];
$question2 = $_POST['question2'];
$question3 = $_POST['question3'];
$question4 = $_POST['question4'];
$question5 = $_POST['question5'];
$mark=0;

$query = "SELECT * FROM footballdb_prototype";
$result = runQuery($dbConn, $query);
if($numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    if ($numrows == 0)
    {
   print "<p>There was nothing in the table</p>";   
   print "</body>";
   print "</html>";
   exit();
   }
echo("some results");

//check to see if answer matches database
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if ("SELECT * FROM footballdb_prototype WHERE '$question1' = question1"){
        $mark += 20;
        }
    if ("SELECT * FROM footballdb_prototype WHERE '$question2' == question2"){
        $mark += 20;
        }
    if ("SELECT * FROM footballdb_prototype WHERE '$question3' == question3"){
        $mark += 20;
       }
    if ("SELECT * FROM footballdb_prototype WHERE '$question4' == question4"){
        $mark += 20;
       }
    if ("SELECT * FROM footballdb_prototype WHERE '$question5' == question5"){
        $mark += 20;
       }

    }
}
else {
echo "we fucked";
}


echo "<p>You scored $mark %";
mysqli_close($dbConn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

HTML Page where variable values are coming from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Think you know?</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Prototype.css" type = "text/css" />
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
</head>
<body class="body">
  <header class = "mainHeader">
 <img src = banner.png>
        <nav><ul>
            <li><a href = "homepage.html">Home </a></li>
            <li class = "active"><a href = "Quiz.php">Quiz</a></li>
              <li> <a href = "Aboutus.html">Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href = "Login.php">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href = "Logout.php">Logout</a></li>
              </ul></nav>
     </header>
     <div class="mainContent">
         <div class = "content">


<head>
    <title>Football Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method=POST action="football_quiz_prototype.php">
        <h1>Think you know your football?<h1>
        <br>
        <h2>What's a hat-trick?</h2>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1 Goal" checked> 1 Goal<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3 Own Goals"> 3 Own Goals<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2 Goals"> 2 Goals<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3 Goals"> 3 Goals<br>

        <br>
        <br>

        <h2>Who won the 2007 UEFA Champions League?</h2>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="AC Milan" checked> AC Milan<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Barcelona"> Barcalona<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Real Madrid"> Real Madrid<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Liverpool"> Liverpool<br>

        <br>
        <br>

        <h2>What is constituted "off-side"?</h2>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Standing behind the midfielders" checked> Standing behind the midfielders<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Standing behind all of the defenders during open-play"> Standing behind all of the defenders during open-play<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Standing outside the pitch"> Standing outside the pitch<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Standing behind all of the defenders during a throw-in"> Standing behind all of the defenders during a throw-in<br>

        <br>
        <br>

        <h2>What is the "Old Firm"?</h2>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="Chelsea vs Arsenal" checked> Chelsea vs Arsenal<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="Celtic vs Barcelona"> Celtic vs Barcelona<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="Rangers vs Motherwell"> Rangers vs Motherwell<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="Celtic vs Rangers"> Celtic vs Rangers<br>

        <br>
        <br>

        <h2>What was the result of the 2014 FIFA World Cup Semi-Final, Germany vs Brazil?</h2>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="Germany: 5 - Brazil: 0" checked> Germany: 5 - Brazil: 0<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="Brazil: 7 - Germany: 1"> Brazil: 7 - Germany: 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="Germany: 7 - Brazil: 1"> Germany: 7 - Brazil: 1<t>
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="Germany: 2 - Brazil: 5"> Germany: 2 - Brazil: 5<br>

        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="submit">
        <input type="reset">
    </form> 
    </content>
    </div>
    <footer class ="mainFooter">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if ("SELECT * FROM footballdb_prototype WHERE '$question1' = question1")` makes no sense. You're just testing the string, you're not performing a query. Shouldn't you be just checking something in `$row` that you're looping over?

Comment: `if ($numrows == 0)` will never succeed, because it's inside `if ($numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result))`, and that only succeeds when there are more than 0 rows.

Comment: I think you if condition inside while loop is wrong

Comment: @Barmar I don't know, should I? If I knew what I should be doing then I wouldn't be asking, would I?

Comment: I can't figure out what your code is trying to do. Post the table contents, and explain what the script is supposed to be doing with it.